# Android ActionBar Tabs behavior on orientation change

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm developing an Android project with ActionBar Tabs.
Tabs are viewed as tabs in portrait mode, and as a drop-down in landscape, as described here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439

My goal is to show images as tab headers while in portrait mode, and text title for drop-down while in landscape.
The idea is to use a custom layout, showing only the required widget.

Here's my code

```
    public class ResultListActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();     
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar
                .newTab()
                .setCustomView(
                        getTabHeaderView(R.string.tab_recommended,
                                R.drawable.ic_action_good))
                .setTabListener(
                        new TabListener<RecommendedFragment>(
                                RecommendedFragment.class)));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar
                .newTab()
                .setCustomView(
                        getTabHeaderView(R.string.tab_favorites,
                                R.drawable.ic_action_important))
                .setTabListener(
                        new TabListener<FavoritesFragment>(
                                FavoritesFragment.class)));
        actionBar
                .addTab(actionBar
                        .newTab()
                        .setCustomView(
                                getTabHeaderView(R.string.tab_nearest,
                                        R.drawable.ic_action_place))
                        .setTabListener(
                                new TabListener<NearestFragment>(
                                        NearestFragment.class)));

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar
                .newTab()
                .setCustomView(
                                getTabHeaderView(R.string.tab_cheapest,
                                        R.drawable.ic_action_dollar_sign))
                .setTabListener(
                        new TabListener<CheapestFragment>(
                                CheapestFragment.class)));
    }    

    private View getTabHeaderView(final int text, final int drawable) {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_header, null);
        ((ImageView) (v.findViewById(R.id.tabIcon))).setImageResource(drawable);
        ((TextView) (v.findViewById(R.id.tabText))).setText(text);
        return v;
    }

    private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements
            ActionBar.TabListener {
    ....
    }
}
```

I've created two XMLs, describing `R.layout.tab_header`, in folders `layout-port` and `layout-land`, with following content

layout-land\tab_header.xml (`ImageView` is gone)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout-port\tab_header.xml (`TextView` is gone)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="2dp" 
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But the results are confusing. (I've got screenshots, but I am not allowed to post them yet, sorry).

- When the application starts in portrait, Tabs are viewed as images.
- After the device is rotated, Tabs turn into drop-down with text header, as intended.
- But after I change my Tab/Drop-Down, Tabs go back into Tabs, without any content.

Thus the question: what is wrong with the appliaction, and, maybe, with the concept?
Perhaps, the is some way to control tabs behavior during orientation changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you aren't using a custom View for the ActionBar itself, it's still necessary to call

```
setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

on your ActionBar. I had this same exact problem today, and this fixed it.